# confirm cancel button not stopping JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a script that trigger when the submit button is clicked.
It has a return confirm javascript. If the user clicks OK, it works fine, but if they click CANCEL, it still triggers by rolling the spinner continuously.

Please help.

Below is the code snippet:

```html
<script>
    //submit search, display loading message
    $('#searchbtn').click(function () {
           
        $('.spinner').css('display', 'block');

    });
</script>
<input type="submit" value="Search" id="searchbtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick=" return confirm('Are you sure to proceed')" />
```

The below is the HTML for those asking.

```
    <p>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("AllLoanProcessed", "Transactions", new { area = "Transactions" }, FormMethod.Get , new { id = "formID" }))
            {

                <b>Search By:</b>
                @Html.RadioButton("searchBy", "Account_Number", true) <text>Account Number</text>
                @Html.RadioButton("searchBy", "Surname") <text> Surname </text> <br />
                @Html.TextBox("search", null, new { placeholder = "Search Value", @class = "form-control" })
                <br />
                <input type="submit" value="Search" id="searchbtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"   />

            }
    </p>
```

Comment: Can you show us the html code of the cancel button?

Comment: @MeesEgberts Pretty sure there is none. It's just like an alert, it gets called in js. No HTML

Comment: Is it possible that the cancel button also contains a spinner with the class `spinner`? Because apply the css to all the spinners

Comment: Post more code. This is not enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write your code like this too, instead of calling click event 2 times you can call it at once, try my below code, this may help you.

```js
$('#searchbtn').click(function () {
  var x = confirm("Are you sure to proceed"); //confirm text
  if (x == true) {  //checking wheather user clicked ok or cancel
   $( "form" ).submit();
   $('.spinner').css('display', 'block');  //if clicked ok spinner shown
  } else {  //else if clicked cancel spinner is hidden
    $('.spinner').css('display', 'none'); 
     return false //stops further process
  }
})
```

```css
.spinner{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<form action="javascript:alert( 'success!' );">
<input type="text"/>
<input type="button" value="Search" id="searchbtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" />

</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="spinner">
my spinner
</h1>
```

change `h1` of the spinner to your spinner,

try it here [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/designerPrasanna/6ufsr1mt/)

Comment: Thank you for this. The spinner do not load when i click on cancel but the action still get triggered

Comment: happy to help, happy coding;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option:

We manually submit the form based on what the user clicks in the confirmation box

```js
function showSpinner(confirmed) {
    if (confirmed) {
        $('.spinner').css('display', 'block');
        $('#formID').submit();
    }
}
```

```css
.spinner{ display: none; }
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Search" id="searchbtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="showSpinner( confirm('Are you sure to proceed') )" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 class="spinner">My spinner</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried that CodeBug example, it worked not bringing the spinner again but the form still triggers

Comment: Check it out now

Comment: I have included the ID but it acts same way. I will Add Edit the question now to include the HTML

Comment: Did you make sure to change the input type to button?

Comment: Thank you for the offer of assistance, but the codebug answer worked. I will however look forward to check out yours more to see it to work too

Answer (score 0):

you need to put more code, this is not enough, but I guess this may help you:

```js
    $('#searchbtn').click(function () {
        $('.spinner').show();
        //start code to search
        
        setInterval(function() {
        
        //finish code to search
        $('.spinner').hide();
        
        }, 5000);

    });

    $('#cancelbtn').click(function () {

        $('.spinner').hide();

    });
```

```css
.spinner{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="spinner"> This is a spinner</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" id="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="searchbtn">Search</button>
```

if you're using bootstrap (I assume this by the class btn btn-danger) the best practice is using an button element. And you can use show hide function.

I hope this can help you.